# format .cls file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: apex, controller, custom-controller

What extension can be used in Visual Studio Code to format `.cls` files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an official Apex code formatter available right now. The GitHub repository for the Salesforce Visual Studio Code extension package has an [open issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/95) for this, and they've solicited feedback on Twitter about their open issues and proposed improvements.

Java formatters often *kind of* work, but don't yield results that look like idiomatic Apex in some cases. I've seen [Uncrustify](https://github.com/LaurentTreguier/vscode-uncrustify) recommended, although I haven't used it myself - it formats Apex as it if were Java.

Comment: Thats very unfortunate. Was afraid this was the ans. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a guide to how to indent Apex in Visual Studio Code https://mrwolf.altervista.org/how-to-indent-apex-code-in-visual-studio-code/

Simply, it's needed to install uncrustify plugin on visual studio code that give you the possibility to indent apex code using the shortcut CTRL + ALT + F . The linked guide explains how to proceed step by step

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi @identigral, do you think now Is Better?

Comment: Better, thank you